# How to enable the hardware virtualization of a HP Probook 4431S laptop in BIOS properly?

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization, vt-x, hp-laptop

I have an HP Probook 4431s laptop. Installed Windows 10 Pro on it.

Device specification is:

> Manufacturer/Model : HP ProBook 4431s Notebook PC (ENERGY STAR)
>
> System type:  X64 based PC
>
> Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M CPU@ 2.70GHz, 2701 MHz, 2
> cores, 4 Logical processors
>
> Disk:  SSD ( 223.57 GB )
>
> RAM: 16 GB
>
> BIOS mode:  Legacy ( BIOS )
>
> OS: Windows 10 Pro (2004 edition)

I want to install [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization) for which i have to first enable the hardware virtualization via BIOS.

Entered in BIOS by pressing F10 on startup -> Go to System setup tab -> device configurations -> enabled options **Virtualization technology** and **Virtualization technology for directed IO** -> save -> exit

After that i booted into windows 10.
When i checked the performance tab of task manager, it shows that

> Virtualization : Disabled.

This causes the docker start failure with error:

> Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be
> enabled in the BIOS

I tried to modify the security settings of virtualization from 'view' to 'change' in BIOS.
But it didn't helped.

Now after trying enabling and disabling these BIOS options, laptop takes alot of tme to boot and sometimes windows fails to respond.

How can i fix this?

Comment: That's not the specification of your laptop. Your CPU is Pentium 2030M, not i7-2620M. (Still, 2030M does support VT-x, so the CPU shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: @gronostaj Sorry, that screenshot is not from my machine. Because my laptop was not booting properly, i added a screenshot of another laptop just to show the virtualization option of task manager. CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M . Edited the question.

Comment: @AnjanaDyna - We need information for **your** machine otherwise we cannot help you.  Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: You should also indicate what version of Windows you are using.  This of course should be provided as an edit to your question instead of a temporary comment.  Any unnecessary commentary will be reported as “no longer being required”.